# scanf with %c and %s causes error

Tags: c

I am trying to scan in an int, a char, a string, and another int. I thought that I would be able to scan in all of them using the following code:

```
int int1, int 2;
char char1;
char* string1;
fscanf(stdin, "%d %c %s %d", &int1, &char1, string1, &int2)
```

but when I run my code it stops abruptly before I can enter all the information. I plan to separate the variables by a newline. My terminal at runtime looks like this:

```
~$ ./program
100
K
word
~$
```

The program closes before I can input int2, which leads me to believe that string1 might not be accounted for either. Any suggestions on how to fix this, or an alternative method that would work more efficiently?

Comment: It's likely `string1` is an invalid pointer.

Comment: use a debugger, generate a stack trace.  Post the stack trace and unabridged code here.

Comment: Is `string1` a `char[]` or a `char*`? If the latter, have you allocated enough memory?

Comment: It would be useful to show the variable declarations.

Comment: Is this format string really the one you are using? Because, this behavior would make complete sense if it were instead `%d%c%s%d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had declared (or allocated) your variables correctly, the line you've given would work as expected.

In this code:

```
    int int1, int2;
    char char1;
    char *string1;

    fscanf(stdin, "%d %c %s %d", &int1, &char1, string1, &int2);
```

As `string1` is uninitialised here this is undefined behaviour. With Linux/glibc, if `string1` happens to contain `0` (NULL), it causes `scanf` to stop processing the format string, and this would produce the same results as you've given. On other systems it might work, it might crash.

This will work as expected:

```
    int int1, int2;
    char char1;
    char string1[20];

    fscanf(stdin, "%d %c %19s %d", &int1, &char1, string1, &int2);
```

Comment: I added in the declarations. I am using a pointer for `string1`, but if an array would work better then I am willing to change it.

Comment: @user2187951 - it's a case of an array will work, and what you have won't. `char *string1;` doesn't allocate any space for the string -- but work with arrays before you get onto things like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
fscanf(stdin, "%d\n %c\n %s\n %d\n", &int1, &char1, string1, &int2)
```

\n - depends on your platform, in some of them instead of \n should be \n\carriege return
So, if explain briefly - you can provide in the "parameter string" symbols which will be excluded from stream, and their order matters.
As you said that you wan`t to place tokens on a new line each then place symbols for a new line in you parameter string

Comment: @teppic be more specific in you comment, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: You don't match newlines in the stream like that. `scanf` doesn't distinguish between newlines, spaces or tabs in a literal format string.

Comment: content of a literal format string affects how input stream will be treated, all literals in provided in a format string, for ex. text, chars and special chars like \n \t \0 and so on will be excluded from stream and all remained will be placed by the specified addresses, provided after format string. If you don`t specify new lines in a literal format string they will be read in char1  for ex.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. The format string the OP gave is perfectly fine.